# Does $\sqrt {-9} = -(9^{1/2})\;?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

The reason I’m asking this question is I know for a fact that the fraction on the power is somewhat the same as root degree…

But I also know as a fact that you cannot calculate the root of a negative number.

So my question basically is :
Does $\,-9^{1/2}$ = $\sqrt{-9}\;?$

Since I believe $-9^{1/2}= -3$ (according to my calculator)

but, when I try $\sqrt{-9}$, it’s undefined

so which one is the correct answer ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $-9^{\frac12}$ is being evaluated as $-\left(9^{\frac12}\right)=-3$. On the other hand, $\sqrt{-9}=(-9)^{\frac12}$ which is not real.

Comment: As I tell my students, parentheses please. Note that $(-9)^\frac{1}{2} \neq -9^\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: The title is different from the body. Powers with non-integer exponent and negative base should be avoided , but as pointed out "-" comes before taking the root if no parantheses are present.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the parentheses

$-(9)^{1/2}$ implies negative of the square root of nine, which is $-3$

$(-9)^{1/2}$ implies square root of negative nine, which is not a real number.

Entering $-9^{1/2}$ would be interpreted as $-(9)^{1/2}$ by the calculator (which is equal to $-3$).